# Flask cuts response at 64KB

Tags: python, nginx, flask

My server is sending response in JSON format with following code:

```py
@app.route('/getfoldercontent')
def getfoldercontent():
    content = get_folder_content_metadata(request.args.get('arg1'), request.args.get('arg2'))
    if content is None:
        res = "Not found"
        rsp_code = 404
    else:
        res = jsonify(content)
        rsp_code = 200
    return res, rsp_code
```

But if the response is bigger than 64KB, it is cut in the middle.

How I can increase this limit?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the nginx that cut the response. After increasing `client_max_body_size` parameter the json is now sent in full.